# How to access the complete runtime GraphQLSchema object with Netflix DGS?

Tags: graphql, graphql-java, netflix-dgs

I need to access the complete `GraphQLSchema` object outside GraphQL request handling. When I used graphql-java directly I was in full control and had the control of this. Right now I need to accomplish the same with Netflix DGS and can't find how to do so (and keep up with runtime changes/reloading later).

For more context - I need to do a few things with this - one is to create a complete, downloadable SDL version of the schema (i.e. not the same as federation `_service { sdl }`) and also gather and expose some directive-driven metadata differently, since I can't introspect it :( from the client...

Answer (score 0):

You can use DgsDataFetchingEnvironment

```
  @DgsQuery
  public Student getStudent(DgsDataFetchingEnvironment dfe) {
      GraphQLSchema schema = dfe.getGraphQLSchema();
      //if you want to know which fields are selected in query
      DataFetchingFieldSelectionSet fields = dfe.getSelectionSet();
  }
```

Comment: That is at request time, within a particular query. I need this independently of that - at or otherwise without GraphQL a request going on.